# Run process before opening file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to achieve the following: every time I attempt to open a file (which is /etc/hosts in this case), a process/script (I don't know what the right term is) starts running. This script would require the user to do some task, e.g. spending x minutes reading some pdf or writing x lines of some document created by this script. Until this task is finished, the file won't open.

Is this possible? Can I achieve it with a bash script? Can I also guarantee that the file doesn't open if the process is somehow interrupted before its finished? And can I trigger the process independently of the way in which I open the file? E.g. from terminal or with the mouse.

I don't know much about computers, so the terminology I am using and the tags below are probably not the best. If this is the case, I apprecaite any convenient edit of the question. Thanks!

Comment: To try to restrict the number of possible ways of opening the file, would you want to do this only when a particular user opens the file for editing (writing), e.g. if someone did `sudo vim /etc/hosts`? What is the underlying issue that you are wanting to solve?

Comment: @Kusalananda I am the only user. Hence, sudo vim /etc/hosts should not be an exception. Neither should be when replacing vim by any other text editor, nor commands like xdg-open. I am trying to avoid procrastination with sites such as Youtube. I can block it via this file. But if I can undo the change any time, it is not much of a help. For this reason I am looking for a system that requires a large amount of effort to change the file back, so that I only do it when it really is necessary. And ideally this effort would be productive, e.g. forcing me to write some tex file or reading some pdf.

Comment: If at all possible. Hand over administration of the system to another trusted human being and get them to change the root password and restrict your `sudo` rights.

Comment: If you've already blocked the sites and now want to stop yourself from unblocking them, I think we've reached the limits of the technical problem and are now in the realms of the human problem :) If your urge to procrastinate is so high you'll go to the trouble of unblocking the site, then you really need to find a non-technical solution. Anything you can do, you can also undo.

Comment: @Kusalananda that's a good Idea, thank you. But I still need my root permissions for many other things on my computer. So that solution doesn't work for me. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: Another idea would be to use a router in a locked cabinet to block the sites. You would not have the key to the cabinet.  But as terdon said, the technical solutions that anyone comes up with here are only partial to solving your underlying issue.

Comment: @Kusalananda that is again a great idea! I could give the key to some trsuted person, as you suggested previously. But is it possible to block sites and unblock them physically from the router? Can't you always do it from the computer?

Comment: Only if you have the password to the router. And the outside connection has to be protected by the cabinet too, so that you can't just plug in a bypass ethernet cable.

Comment: Dear @terdon, I assume you meant well with your comment and it is a very valid point. But 1) Your comment is unrelated to the technical problem I am discussing (this is not psychology stack exchange); 2) I am aware that anything you can do you can also undo, but as I already stated, I am just trying to make the undo process more difficult, which I think should be technically possible; hence 3) I don't think we have "reached the limits of the technical problem". And in any case, changing a line of a file is pretty much nothing, so you could also argue "why do you need to block sites at all?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop yourself, as root, to undo the blocking of a website, you will have to give up control of the blocking and unblocking process and involve another human being.

The radical solution would be to just give up root privileges on the machine to some other trusted human, and at least to severely restrict the available operations that you can do through `sudo`.  On a Unix system, virtually all software can be installed in one's home directory, if one's willing to put one's mind to it.

The other solution is to move the actual blocking process from the machine entirely, and let that be handled by a separate piece of equipment, like a locked-away router. Note that the router would also need to block tunneling through SSH, and other creative ways of connecting through other machines.

The protection of the router's configuration and  physical access would also include protection of the external network outlet as to not allow you to tamper with the blocking by unplugging the router and bypassing it with an ethernet cable.

The key for accessing the router, and the router's admin password, would not be in your possession.

There might also be something one could do with virtual machines or containers (or possibly even just a chroot), so that the external connection would be protected by "another system" (the host machine) which you have no easy access to, while you work on the virtual machine or in the container.

I believe this is the limit to the technical solutions to your issue.  As such, they are not limited to Unix systems.  The next step would be to work with personal behaviour in other ways, such as through changing the way you work (always be visible by someone who cares), or seek outside help from a behaviour therapist or similar.